# Is there a backstory to the character Saavik?

Tags: star-trek, the-wrath-of-khan, the-search-for-spock

Who exactly is Saavik? The crew didn't speak of her on the first movie but she just shows up on the second one. Is she related to Spock?

Comment: @NKCampbell Stack Exchange tends to view lmgtfy comments as really rude, to the point where links to the original site [were outright banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/191265). I don't think that's an appropriate comment, especially for a new user.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Saavik / http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Saavik - didn't know that @Thunderforge - that's a meta from 2009 on the main site. I've seen that kind of response before for easily searched for information. Apologies for breaching community standards

Answer (score 2):

There is considerable detail regarding Saavik and her backstory in the novel of The Wrath of Khan. Dialogue that would have explained more of her story was edited out of the film of Wrath of Khan, possibly to keep the running time under control. The backstory is that she was rescued by Spock from a planet called Hellguard and raised by Spock's parents, you could perhaps consider her an adopted family member but there is no blood relationship. According to the Wikipedia entry on this character this is not considered cannon information as it contradicts story elements from an original series episode that featured Romulus story. Part of the backstory discusses an attack by romulans on hellguard. You can read the Wikipedia entry here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saavik

Comment: Spock had *another* adopted sibling?!

Comment: He has three, I believe.